# How to improve speed of complex for-loop?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have some stratified data and need to apply an operation to each strata separately. I managed to do that with a for loop (see example below). However, the loop is way too slow, since I am dealing with a huge data set. I am sure there must be a way to speed things up, e.g. with `apply` functions, but unfortunately I was not able to find a better solution.

**Question: How could I improve the speed of this operation?**

```
# Some example data (do not care about the data creation, only the loop is important)

set.seed(123)

N <- 100

strata <- round(runif(N, 1, 1000)) # Strata

x1 <- rpois(N, lambda = 50) # Variable 1
x2 <- rpois(N, lambda = 50) # Variable 2

ind1 <- as.factor(rbinom(N, 1, 0.3)) # Group indicator 1
ind2 <- as.factor(rbinom(N, 1, 0.6)) # Group indicator 2

x1[ind1 == 0] <- 0
x2[ind1 == 0] <- 0
x1[ind2 == 0] <- 0
x2[ind2 == 1] <- 0

x1_sum <- sum(x1)
x2_sum <- sum(x2)

# # # # # The folowing loop is too slow # # # # #

new_values <- x2 # Apply the following operation strata by strata

for(i in 1:length(table(strata))) {

  x1_sum_strata <- sum(x1[strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]])

  x2_sum_strata <- sum(x2[strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]])

  new_values[x1 == 0 & ind1 == 1 & strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]] <- 
    (x1_sum / x2_sum) * (x1_sum_strata / x2_sum_strata)
}
```

Comment: First of all I wouldn't calculate `table(strata)` all the times... just store the result before the loop and use that e.g. : `tbl <- table(strata)`... then I think you could use `split(1:N,strata)` to obtain the indexes of strata having the same values and use them to subset `strata`,`x1` and `x2` in the loops without using the condition `strata == as.num...` every time (which is slower since it enumerates all the vector all the times)

Comment: If you want to make a change only when `strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))` then put this in a variable and loop over it ..no ? But can you explain the meaning of this condition ?

Comment: `as.numeric(names(table(strata)))` is mostly just a complicated way of saying `unique(strata)`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Seems like I underestimated how long functions such as `as.numeric` or `table` take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# # # # # loop # # # # #

new_values <- x2 # Apply the following operation strata by strata

st <- table(strata)
sst <- as.numeric(names(st))
i1 <- x1 == 0 
i2 <- ind1 == 1
is <- i1 & i2
for(i in 1:length(st)) {
  ii  <- strata == sst[i]
  x1_sum_strata <- sum(x1[ii])
  x2_sum_strata <- sum(x2[ii])

  new_values[is & ii] <-  (x1_sum / x2_sum) * (x1_sum_strata / x2_sum_strata)
}
```

Benchmark:

```
N <- 10000
rbenchmark::benchmark(antonios(), minem(), replications= 10)
#         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 antonios()           10    8.77   11.101      5.58     1.70         NA        NA
# 2    minem()           10    0.79    1.000      0.76     0.02         NA        NA
```

Comment: With N = 10000 and my code: 42.66904 secs; with your code: 0.1410141 secs. Impressive! I applied your code to my real data and there it also worked. Thank you very much for this perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think @digEmAll is right, the bottleneck is not in your loop. Let's make the data a bit larger:

```
set.seed(123)

N <- 1000
strata <- round(runif(N, 1, 10000)) # Strata
x1 <- rpois(N, lambda = 50) # Variable 1
x2 <- rpois(N, lambda = 50) # Variable 2

ind1 <- as.factor(rbinom(N, 1, 0.3)) # Group indicator 1
ind2 <- as.factor(rbinom(N, 1, 0.6)) # Group indicator 2

x1[ind1 == 0] <- 0
x2[ind1 == 0] <- 0
x1[ind2 == 0] <- 0
x2[ind2 == 1] <- 0

x1_sum <- sum(x1)
x2_sum <- sum(x2)

# # # # # The folowing loop is too slow # # # # #

new_values <- x2 # Apply the following operation strata by strata
```

Now with your approach it takes about 10s in my PC to run

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:length(table(strata))) {
+   x1_sum_strata <- sum(x1[strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]])
+   x2_sum_strata <- sum(x2[strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]])
+   new_values[x1 == 0 & ind1 == 1 & strata == as.numeric(names(table(strata)))[i]] <- 
+     (x1_sum / x2_sum) * (x1_sum_strata / x2_sum_strata)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   9.67    0.02    9.71 
>
```

but if you set as.numeric(names(table(strata))) in a new variable, it runs  about 100 times faster:

```
> x=as.numeric(names(table(strata)))
> system.time(for(i in 1:length(table(strata))) {
+   x1_sum_strata <- sum(x1[strata == x[i]])
+   x2_sum_strata <- sum(x2[strata == x[i]])
+   new_values[x1 == 0 & ind1 == 1 & strata == x[i]] <- (x1_sum / x2_sum) * (x1_sum_strata / x2_sum_strata)
+ }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.11 
>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I never would have expected that such a simple change would result in such an improvement. I have accepted minem's answer, since it improved my code even more. But thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to write a function that operates on a single stratum, and that performs only the necessary calculations for that stratum; you can  then debug the function for the edge cases, etc.

```
f = function(x, y) sum(x) / sum(y)
```

Taking the 'tidyverse' to heart, it often makes sense to think in terms of tibbles (data.frames) and a few simple operations (group the data by strata; summarize each group) to be performed on them

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl = tbl(x1, x2, strata)
ans0 = group_by(tbl, strata) %>% summarize(value = f(x1, x2))
```

One can then think about how this result can be modified to get the final answer, e.g., by scaling the value of each strata by the value from the full data

```
ans = mutate(ans0, value = f(tbl$x1, tbl$x2) * value)
```

One nice thing about this is that the result is a tibble, so the whole process can be repeated with the same sorts of operations for the next step in the analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I definitely should spend some more learning time for the tidyverse!